# AngularJS - String with bolds. Separation of concerns between controller and templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have an application in AngularJS, version 1, with Ecmascript 6 where I wanted to show a string, where one part would be in normal weight, and another in bold.

For example, the following situations:

- Will **start now**
- Will start **in 6 minutes**
- Will start **in 12 months**

Which way you would use, since I wanted to avoid having presentation logic in the controllers.

Send to the templates two properties with the string that should be normal, and another with what should be in bold? This way I would have logic of presentation in the controllers. Some kind of template strings?

Comment: A sample code of what you're trying to achieve would help us to understand more precisely the situation and give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my Angular Project, i am replacing the targetstring with html binded value to show bolded text in the template.

In Controller:

```
private replaceString() {
let someString = 'hello world';
$scope.formattedString = someString.replace('world', '<span>world</span>');
}
```

Template:

```
<div ng-bind-html="formattedString"></div>
```

FYI:

Use $sce.trustAsHtml for announcing angular to trust your value or else angular will reject it for (ng-bind-html) cases. 
link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it makes sense, but either way we wanted to avoid making HTML concatenation in the controller, so we split the string into an object with properties that fit.